# Filter spreadsheet by user-entered value in first row

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, regex, google-sheets-filter

In Google Sheets, I want to set up a filtered view like this.

```
Row 1 = column headings  
Row 2 = filter criteria  
Rows 3... = data
```

I want the user to type a value into any column of row 2, and this will dynamically update which rows are displayed in the filter view.  Is this possible?  For example, starting with column C, I enter "Disney" into C2, then I enter this formula as a filter, but it returns only row 2.

```
=REGEXMATCH(C2, $C$2)
```

But if I enter it as `=REGEXMATCH(C2, "Disney")` then it correctly returns all rows with Disney in column C.

Here is an example spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o3cvenwSuimKo9gZuehqo8Y-LEZ_c397JJk7LNmfwQM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 2):

This won't be possible because you unintentionally create a circular reference by referring **$C$2** from inside of the range **C1:C**. Therefore you will need to put it outside of the box like for example by swapping 1st & 2nd row and creating green filtered view from 2nd row onwards:

[image: 0]

```
=REGEXMATCH(C3, $C$1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This works, thank you!  But I have to turn the filter view off and on again to refresh it.  Is there some way to make it refresh as soon as I change the C1 cell?  I will make the first row all data validation dropdown lists